# VB.NET: Keeping class namespaces in sync with folder structure

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

After being spoiled for years with C# automatically setting the default namespace for new classes to match my folder structure, I'm wondering if there is any way to get VB.NET to do the same?

I've been aware for awhile that it doesn't do this automatically but I've never really researched alternatives.  Any tools or tricks to help me keep my VB.NET class namespaces in sync with my project folder structures?

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Resharper for VB.NET](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), It works great and is a fraction of the cost of the C# version.

Comment: Are you sure that Resharper does this? Can you point out where this feature is explained?

Comment: Someone posted a duplicate to this question in July, 2010. The duplicate question has a great answer. You can read it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317141/automatically-add-namespace-when-adding-new-item