# The name "..." does not exist in namespace ".." Visual Studio 2017

Tags: wpf

I'm working on a WPF project which uses ".Net Framework 4.6.2" on Visual Studio 2017.

I got a dll file from internet named "GrayscaleEffect" and added it to references.

In xaml file i added

```
xmlns:grayScaleEffect="clr-namespace:GrayscaleEffect;assembly=GrayscaleEffect"
```

And using it like this :

```
<Image.Effect>                                                   
      <grayScaleEffect:GrayscaleEffect x:Name="grayscaleEffect"/>
</Image.Effect>
```

When i run the application it works, but in xaml editor it gives an error :

```
The name "GrayscaleEffect" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:GrayscaleEffect;assembly=GrayscaleEffect"....
```

I tried rebuilding the project and restarting Visual Studio but it didnt solve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051121/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespace. If you still cannot get rid of the error you may want to disable the designer: http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/03/24/disable-the-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I removed the referance, right click on dll file and selected "Unblock File", added to the references and everyting is fine now.