# MVVM - The name does not exist in the name space

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to start a MVVM pattern and I have this structure:

[image]

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="StereoVisionApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StereoVisionApp"
             StartupUri="MainView.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:MainViewModel x:Key="StereoVisionApp.MainViewModel"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
namespace StereoVisionApp.ViewModels
{
    class MainViewModel 
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have an error on this line:

```
<local:MainViewModel x:Key="StereoVisionApp.MainViewModel"/>
```

Says:

> The name "MainViewModel" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:StereoVisionApp".  StereoVisionApp C:\Users\Me\source\repos\StereoVisionApp\StereoVisionApp\App.xaml

I have tried [**restarting**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15247754/6540193) million times. any help?

Comment: The `MainViewModel` is probably in `StereoVisionApp.ViewModels`, not the base namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, when you create a new folder in the project at creates a new namespace named `projectname.foldername` by default. (in your case: `StereoVisionApp.ViewModels`). All the files inside it automatically takes that namespace.

You can either:

1. Change the namespace in `MainViewModel.cs`
   or
2. Add the new namespace to `App.xaml` like this:

add this in `Application` header in `App.xaml`

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:StereoVisionApp.ViewModels"
```

Then use it like this:

```
<vm:MainViewModel x:Key="StereoVisionApp.MainViewModel"/>
```

Also note that the `x:Key` value is a string of your choice (doesn't have to be an exact location, so you can actually write:

```
<vm:MainViewModel x:Key="mainViewModel"/>
```

The `x:Key` value is for future reference only.

Comment: I did the above and then restarted VS, it seems working now :)