# How can I fix error code XDG0062 In VS2022 WPF .net 3.2

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am making a game engine and I was codding a new UI and it is giving the following error "Error XDG0062    'StaticResourceExtension' is not valid for Setter.Value. The only supported MarkupExtension types are DynamicResourceExtension and BindingBase or derived types."

Here is the only code that was added since the last working build

ControlTemplate.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="Pico_Editor.Dictionaries.ControlTemplates"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pico_Editor.Dictionaries">
    
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TextBoxStyle">
        <!-- TODO: define the look of textbox here -->
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}">
        <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="OnTextBox_KeyDown"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="PicoWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Editor.Selected.BackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Editor.Window.GrayBrush1}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

EditorColors.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pico_Editor.Dictionaries">

    <!-- Editor Colors -->
    <Color x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayColor1">            #ff1f1f1f</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayColor2">            #ff262626</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayColor3">            #ff313131</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayColor4">            #ff404040</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayColor5">            #ff535353</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayColor6">            #ff6a6a6a</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.Disabled.FontColor">           #ff868686</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.FontColor">                    #ffdddddd</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.RedColor">                     #ffff5a6a</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.GreenColor">                   #ff90ee90</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.BlueColor">                    #ff80deff</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.OrangeColor">                  #ffffd067</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Editor.Selected.BackgroundColor">     #ff3c67b6</Color>

    <!-- Editor Brushes -->
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.Window.GrayColor1}"          x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayBrush1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.Window.GrayColor2}"          x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayBrush2"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.Window.GrayColor3}"          x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayBrush3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.Window.GrayColor4}"          x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayBrush4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.Window.GrayColor5}"          x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayBrush5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.Window.GrayColor6}"          x:Key="Editor.Window.GrayBrush6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.Disabled.FontColor}"     x:Key="Editor.Disabled.FontBrush"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.FontColor}"                  x:Key="Editor.FontBrush"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.RedColor}"                   x:Key="Editor.RedBrush"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.GreenColor}"             x:Key="Editor.GreenBrush"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.BlueColor}"                  x:Key="Editor.BlueBrush"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.OrangeColor}"                x:Key="Editor.OrangeBrush"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Editor.Selected.BackgroundColor}"   x:Key="Editor.Selected.BackgroundBrush"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I also added `Style="{StaticResource PicoWindowStyle}"` to the window section of my main window

Any help will be appreciated I have no clue what the problem is and i cnat see anything wrong with the code

Comment: I forgot that xaml has top down code flow and my App.xalm file had
`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dictionaries/ControlTemplates.xaml"/>`
on top of 
`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dictionaries/EditorColors.xaml"/>`
but it had to be the other way around

Comment: Did you see this one?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052601/visual-studio-xaml-designer-error-xdg0062-using-eventsetter-in-net-core-wpf-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that xaml has top down code flow and my App.xalm file had

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dictionaries/ControlTemplates.xaml"/>`

on top of

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dictionaries/EditorColors.xaml"/>` but it had to be the other way around