# Xaml File does not see Class from a Namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, namespaces

Why does the `App.xml` not find the Class `CaptionButtonRectToMarginConverter`within the `Shell \ CaptionButtonRectToMarginConverter.cs` File ?

```
Error XDG0008 File App.xml Line 13

The name "CaptionButtonRectToMarginConverter" does not exist in the namespace
"clr-namespace:ErdBuilder.Shell".
```

**App.xml**

```
<nRoute:Application x:Class="ErdBuilder.App"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:nRoute="http://nRoute/schemas/2010/xaml"
                    xmlns:chronos="http://chronos/schemas/2010/xaml"
                    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:ErdBuilder.Shell"
                    StartupUri="Shell\Shell.xaml"
                    ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">

    <nRoute:Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <shell:CaptionButtonRectToMarginConverter x:Key="CaptionButtonMarginConverter" />
```

**Shell \ CaptionButtonRectToMarginConverter.cs**

```
namespace ErdBuilder.Shell
{
    public class CaptionButtonRectToMarginConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the name <...> does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace <...>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051121/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespace)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The name “XYZ” does not exist in the namespace “clr-namespace:ABC”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16216662/4977870)