# Control Does Not Exist in Namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I'm attempting to use the `MediaUriElement` in the custom ([WPFMediaKit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit)).

I've added it into the namespace like so;

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"
```

and then I have tried to access it;

```
<Grid>
    <controls:MediaUriElement x:Name="mediaUriElement" />
</Grid>
```

however I just get an error: *The name MediaUriElement does not exist in this namespace.* VS does give me a suggestion to use it when I am typing though;

[image]

How can I correctly add this into my project?

Comment: may this helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665713/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-error-in-xaml

Comment: @un-lucky unfortunately none of the answers seem to have fixed my issue

Comment: Is is because your project cannot compile or does it just bother you with the blue underline ? I have exact same scenario in some of my projects, but the project is compiling just fine, so I assumed that there was some bug in VS.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada It wouldn't bother me at all, however the project won't compile which is the issue here

Comment: Sometimes, if you have errors somewhere else in your code you will face same problem. Even if the problem isn't here, VS will indicate it as a problem here. Clean your solution, and rebuild it. Check the Error list, and fix all other errors, sometimes this kind of errors disappear when other errors are fixed.

Comment: Have you added `WPFMEdiaKit` dll to your project ?

Comment: @StepUp I have added it as a reference yes

Comment: so, just do it as Nawed Nabi Zada said. Sometimes red rows happens, but it is not a reason to be scaried:). Just write your code without `IntelliSense`.

Comment: @StepUp the program will not compile it isn't just a designer error

Answer (score 0):

I've tried and it is worked. What I've done:

1. Switched project from `Framework 4.5` to `Framework 4.0`
2. Added references such as `DirectShowLib-2005.dll` and `WPFMediaKit.dll` to the project
3. Declared xaml namespace `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"` like that:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="ExcelExportWpfApplication.MainWindow"
       ... The code omitted for the brevity...
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"
       xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ExcelExportWpfApplication.ViewModel"        
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="525" 
             WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
   ```
4. And just written in xaml:

   ```
   <controls:MediaUriElement Grid.Row="2"/>
   ```
5. No errors

Comment: @CBreeze it is really interesting why don't you upvote answers or assign as answer replies to your thread? If you upvote replies, you'll take more treat by others.