# The property "Class" does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" namespace

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building an app using Xamarin.Forms and while making a XAML page I get the following error:

> The property "Class" does not exist in the
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" namespace.

This is not the first page I've made and all other pages seem to work fine except for this one. I've checked the references and the properties of said file and they all seem fine.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<controls:ViewPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   x:Class="XXXX"
                   xmlns:controls="XXXX"
</controls:ViewPage>
```

The code behind is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XXXX;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XXXX
{
    public partial class ActOverviewView : ViewPage, IActOverviewView
    {
        public ActOverviewView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Have you inherited your `behind class` from `ViewPage`? Put your behind code for this page, too.

Comment: Okay I added it. I've looked at it with 3 different professional programmers (excluding myself) and one of them suggested that it may be that Xamarin doesn't deal very well with UWP, could that be what's causing this?

Comment: I don't think so, also you told, that all other pages work fine. Maybe, `xmlns:controls` namespace is wrong

Comment: The other pages are not UWP, but droid and IOS so that's why we thought that maybe that's the problem. I've checked all namespaces etc. multiple times, so I don't think that's it. I've just skipped the UWP for now and will maybe pick it up later if I have enough time unless someone here comes with a solution :).

Comment: Make sure the xaml file is an embeddedresource and that the generator is set to "MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml"

Comment: also, could you give the stack trace for you error ? I wonder where this comes from, Xamarin.Forms parser or another one...

Comment: @Stinna Are you trying to create a Template page or normal page ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<controls:ViewPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   x:Class="XXXX.ActOverviewView"
                   xmlns:controls="XXXX"
</controls:ViewPage>
```

Comment: @RichardHammond Seems like an accurate description of Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665713/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-error-in-xaml):

I copy/paste the solution:

I've seen this issue go away by clearing the Xaml Design Shadow Cache. I had the issue with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

In Visual Studio 2015 the Cache is located here:

%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache Process:

- Right-Click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and Choose "Clean Solution"
- Shutdown Visual Studio
- Delete the ShadowCache folder
- Reopened the Visual Studio project
- Rebuild the solution

And voila no more namespace errors.