# How can I make Visual Studio 2015 add a new VB.NET class with a namespace declaration?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, namespaces

Whenever I add a new VB.NET class, VS 2015 totally ignores any namespace declaration, because it's "automatically in the default namespace, but I want my classes namespaced by folder name as well. Plus I want explicit namespace declarations on all my classes.

Right now, I add a class, ReSharper squiggles it, and I elect to have it moved to the correct namespace. Is there no VS setting to always include the namespace 'wrapper' when creating a new VB.NET class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3317333/386703)?

Comment: @Brandon The answer to that question doesn't work in VS 2015.

Comment: I was able to get it to work up to the actual name of the namespace. You can include the root namespace but nothing more. Not helpful in VB

Comment: When I add a new class, I get `Namespace $itemfolder$`. It does no replacment at all. I tried adding the extra `WizardExtension` element to `Class.vstemplate`, I got a runtime error.  I'll just code my MVVM setup in C#, and the client's form and code in VB.NET, and tell him the rest came out the box, hehe.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd gotten too. I tried with `$rootnamespace$` but it only bought me `Namespace WindowsApplication1`. I'm kind of annoyed at this now.

Comment: `Is there no VS setting to always include the namespace` no there is not I am afraid. Although it wont help you now, I am actually working on an extension that has this functionality... Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

There's no setting for that in VS. You have to manually fight the VB framework in this case.

1. Unload the project.
2. Hand-edit the project file, setting RootNamespace to an empty string.

   ```
   <RootNamespace></RootNamespace>
   ```
3. Reload the project and create your folder structure.

   [image: Solution structure]

Namespaces will work like C# without VS or Resharper complaining:

[image]

Comment: Why the down vote here? It didn't work for me, but I'm pretty sure it did for @nunzabar..I've offset it, so it won't show any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the root namespace for a project:

1- With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.

2- Click the Application tab.

3- In the Root namespace field, enter the name.

Comment: That still doesn't cause new classes to be wrapped in it. VB just sucks.