# Visual Studio, VB.NET and Namespaces

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, namespaces, visual-studio-2017

How can I make my VS2017 automatically add namespaces to new *.vb files?

I tried to create new item templates using `$itemfolder$`, but it doesn't work:

**Template**

```
Namespace $itemfolder$

    Public Class $safeitemrootname$

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Output**

```
Namespace $itemfolder$

    Public Class MyClass2

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Using the `$rootnamespace$` parameter, it doens't work as I'm expecting:

**Template**

```
Namespace $itemfolder$

    Public Class $safeitemrootname$

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Output**

```
Namespace ConsoleApp1

    Public Class MyClass

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Solution Explorer**

[image]

I was expecting the namespace to be `ConsoleApp1.TestNamespace` or `TestNamespace` in that case.

Is there any way to VS2017 automatically add namespaces to my new classes?
I also know that Resharper can do this job, but I'm looking for a free solution.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have been on the right track but you may have missed a step. There's a command you have to execute from the command line: `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` as seen on [this thread here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317141/automatically-add-namespace-when-adding-new-item) Have a look and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for awnsering. Also did that, didn't work at all.