# Can't create a new namespace in VB.Net project using VS 2019

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to define new namespaces and classes within a new VB.NET project; however, Visual Studio is not allowing me to instantiate any of my new namespaces/classes/methods.

I have.....

1. set up a new project in Visual Studio 2019 Community;
2. created a new namespace (SignInSignOut) with a single class (TestClass) and one method (ShowMessageBox);
3. attempted to Import the new namespace into an existing code-behind page (Default.aspx.vb); and
4. attempted to instantiate the new class and method from the Page_Load() method of the code-behind page.

The attempt to Import the new namespace into the existing code-behind page fails.

The new Namespace, Class and Method.....

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Namespace SignInSignOut
    Public Class TestClass
        Public Shared Sub ShowMessageBox(ByVal sString As String)
            MsgBox(sString)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The attempt to import the Namespace.Class and instantiate the Method on the Default.aspx.vb code-behind page.....

```
Imports SignInSignOut.TestClass

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        ShowMessageBox("This is just a test!")

    End Sub
End Class
```

### Edit

I resolved the issue by re-installing Visual Studio 2019 Community.  I had reinstalled an old copy of VS 2010 Pro and the example worked as expected, which led me to believe I might have a problem with VS 2019 Community.

Comment: Does your project that contains `TestClass` have a Root namespace specified in the project properties?  Also, if you're getting errors, you should include them in your question.

Comment: To avoid any ambiguity due to VB's default Namespace, consider rooting your added Namespace to the  [Global Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/namespaces#global-keyword-in-namespace-statements).

Answer (score 4):

Four things I noticed so far:

1. Import namespaces, not classes (at least for the moment):

   ```
   Imports SignInSignOut

   Public Class _Default
       Inherits Page

       Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

           TestClass.ShowMessageBox("This is just a test!")

       End Sub
   End Class
   ```
2. Make sure that's the *full name* for the namespace, and you haven't inherited a higher-level namespace from your project:

   ```
   Imports MyProjectName.SignInSignOut
   ```
3. ASP.NET Webforms is picky about where that code should live. Put it in the `App_Code` folder in the solution.
4. `MsgBox()` won't do what you expect in a webforms project. It **will** open a message box, but it will do it on the *web server* and **not** in the browser on the user's machine. The message box will still block the thread until someone dismisses it, which is a problem for your web server.

Comment: Joel,  Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, the full namespace approach (step #2) also fails.  There is no option for 'WebApp1.SignInSignOut'.  Indeed the new file was placed inside the App_Code folder.  Yes, I realize the MsgBox method will break a web app on a production server; however, it works fine while debugging with localhost.

Answer (score 2):

In visual basic, generally, namespaces works in 2 parts (unlike c#). When you create project, it automatically creates a namespace for you, which you can see in project properties - `Default Namespace`. This is where you initially will find same value as in `Assembly Name` and original project name. for now, lets assume, this name is `MyWebProject`

Now, as you add a new file, it will not add `Namespace` block. You have automatic namespace `MyWebProject`. If you add namespace block, like `MyFirstNamespace`, your class within this block will be - `MyWebProject.MyFirstNamespace`, hence 2-part namespace in VB.net.

Comment: Is there any setting that can add namespace in newly added files as per folder structure?

Comment: @HaiderAliWajihi looks like there is an answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317141/automatically-add-namespace-when-adding-new-item